# Creating Webservice Programmatically on Wildfly/JBoss application server

Tags: java, wildfly

I know that Webservice can be created by using annotation @Webservice and Wildfly automatically creates instance of it.
But I have configuration file where I have defined webservice url and I want to create programatically webservice using this url. For spring endpoint can be created as follows:

```
@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint() {
     EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), new BaeldungImpl());
     endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/services/baeldung");
     return endpoint;
}
```

Unfortunatelly my application does not use spring but CDI.
Can some suggest me how can I do it correctly?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Why do you want to? What are you trying to do that the normal annotation method does not support?